# Performance drops when using modulo on double

Tags: java, performance, double, modulo

Using the modulo operator on double is slower than using **this** function, in a specific test I wrote.

```
final static double fastmod(double a, double b){
return a - b*(long)(a/b);
}
```

It's was a sin() function test, but what I want to discuss is the modulo on double performance.

EDIT: Removed sin() test link.
      Added test only testing modulo.

https://ideone.com/6zqxBR

Intuitively I think the % operator should be faster but the test sais it's slower.
Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Micro-benchmarks are notoriously unreliable, I have not investigated thoroughly but I strongly suspect your benchmarking methodology is flawed.

Comment: Thank's for your comment I suspect so to.

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/504103)

Comment: Why do you think the `%` operator should be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Your `fastmod` is indeed faster, but not equivalent to `%`.

With the arguments produced by `Math.random()*100` your implementation gives a good approximation, however, the result is not necessarily equals to the result of `%` operation due loss of precision when converting to `long`, e.g.

```
    System.out.println(7.4 % 2.1);          // 1.1
    System.out.println(fastmod(7.4, 2.1));  // 1.0999999999999996
```

Also `fastmod` does not correctly handle large values and various corner cases:

```
    System.out.println(1E20 % 2);          // 0.0
    System.out.println(fastmod(1E20, 2));  // 8.155325592629045E19

    System.out.println(1 % Double.MIN_VALUE);          // 0.0
    System.out.println(fastmod(1, Double.MIN_VALUE));  // 1.0
```

In fact, your implementation is simplified, and this allows it to be faster than 'correct' remainder. If you don't care about numbers beyond `long` range, and if you realize inaccuracies that may happen in ~15th digit, it is completely OK to use faster `fastmod`.

Comment: Probably removing the `(long)` cast would improve accuracy and performance. Overflow would still be an issue though.